# Panel header leaves padding with panel border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

Above snippet is a result of the following code-(i have used bootstrap for the css)

```
<div class="container" >
            <div id=" row" style="margin-top: 140px;">
                <div class="panel col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: gray">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel col-md-6" style="background-color: greenyellow">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: sienna;width:fit-content;"></div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
```

Here Green and yellow are panels; Sienna and grey are panel headers. Why does panel header leave padding on both ends? how to fit header here to panel width?

Comment: you can set padding 0 to the class panel

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use col-md-* with other classes. It's part of the grid system and the "cells" are padded to the left and right.

This should be your code, although it doesn't fix your problem:
You shouldn't use col-md-* with other classes. It's part of the grid system.
You need to use some more div elements like so:

```
         <div class="container" >
            <div id=" row" style="margin-top: 140px;">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow">
                    <div class="pannel">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: gray">

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: greenyellow">
                    <div class="pannel">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: sienna">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.row` class add a negative padding of 15px.

`.col-xx-xx` class add a positive padding of 15px.

To don't have this padding, just remove it in your specific class.

Here :

```
.panel{
   padding: 0px;
}
```